# Alinear items utilizando flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Saludos a toda la comunidad, estoy adentrándome en el mundo de boostrap, necesito ayuda para alinear 6 items mediante flexbox de forma que queden como una escalera , a continuacion muestro una foto de los items

[!Items a ordenar[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0zo2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0zo2.png)

Esto ya lo hice con solo 3 items  mediante align-self.

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background: gray;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  
}

.hijo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 40px
}

.arriba {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.centro {
  align-self: center;
}

.abajo {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="hijo abajo">A</div>
    <div class="hijo centro">B</div>
    <div class="hijo arriba">C</div>

  </div>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Podrás mostrar el código que fuiste haciendo hasta ahora?

Comment: Revisa porfa la sig. url, saludos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229387/flexbox-margin-and-offseting-issue-with-stair-effect

Answer (score 1):

Buen tarde, podrías revisar algo como lo que presenta el siguiente example:

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell top">Celda en el top</div>
  <div class="cell ancha">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras mollis mi a diam tempor, sit amet fermentum turpis posuere. Phasellus a auctor dolor, et feugiat eros. Etiam id quam mauris. Curabitur libero nisi, dignissim sed urna quis, malesuada tristique arcu. Sed purus urna, facilisis sit amet maximus placerat, pharetra eu nisi.</div>
  <div class="cell center">Centro</div>
  <div class="cell bottom">Abajo</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid{
  display: flex;
}

.cell{
  width: 25%;  
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
.top{
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.center{
  align-self: center;
}

.bottom{
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Ahora bien aquí se juega con los lineamientos css de flexbox como son arriba(top), abajo(bottom), centro(center)... y también con el contenido que tiene tus div... en todo caso seria necesario revisar para hacerlo dinámico a n items que existan en tus obj.

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Bibliografía: https://codepen.io/egomezd/pen/peRERK